# HTML range element to control volume of audio element

Tags: javascript, html, audio, range

I'm trying to use the HTML range element to control the volume of an HTML audio element but running into some problems.

The setVolume function below is only one line and seemed to work in another answer on this site, and alongside the error I am getting ("Uncaught ReferenceError: setVolume is not defined") I feel like I am having trouble activating the function in the first place.

Anyone have any ideas?

Relavent HTML:

```
<div class="slides">
   <div class="slider-cont">
   <input type="range" onchange="setVolume()" id='volume1' min=0 max=1 step=0.01 value='0.30'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script for the audio player:

```
window.onload = function() {
var audioPlayer = function() {
    var rainPlaying = false;
    var playRain = document.getElementById('playRain');
    var rainAudio = new Audio('audio/rain1.ogg');
    rainAudio.id = "rainLoop";
    rainAudio.loop = true;

    playRain.addEventListener('click', function() {
        if (rainPlaying) {
            rainPlaying = false;
            rainAudio.pause();

        } else {
            rainPlaying = true;
            rainAudio.play();

        }
    }, false);
    var setVolume = function() {
        rainAudio.volume = document.getElementById("volume1").value;
    };
  }();
};
```

Comment: Is setVolume a function or a attribute?

Comment: A function that is triggered whenever the value of the range element is changed, or at least it's supposed to be!

Comment: Sorry I misread the code.

Comment: I would recommend using `addEventListener()` instead of `onchange="... "`. It's cleaner to keep HTML seperat from JS

Answer (score 1):

`setVolume` is a local variable, available only to the scope of the function. That's why it's undefined. You can make it a global variable by removing the `var` keyword.

While this is generally not a good practice, in this case your code will work.

Look at this fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/xyjn4mao/

Open up your console, you will no longer get a `Reference Error`.

Comment: Hmm yeah the function works with the var keyword removed, thank you very much! I wouldn't like to carry on with bad practices though! How would you recommend accessing the function without making it global?

Comment: That's an excellent question. I'm not sure about that myself. I try to avoid globals, but in this case, I would probably do the same thing